# Postgresql admin tool with user management, logging and data backup

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking for something like [Gogs](https://try.gogs.io) for [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git), but for [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org). Self hosted management tool with SQL/DB editor, user management tool (external, not the `PostgreSQL` has), logging and some sort of data backup (if possible).

I understand that its very broad and specific list of requirements, but I feel like there should be something for that purpose.

I know that I could achieve everything using solely `PostgreSQL` functionality with proper configuration and use whatever client I want. Actually for now it's the only valid free option I see.

Also I'm aware about [JackDB](https://www.jackdb.com), which seems to be like best option, pretty pricy one though.

Answer (score 2):

[pgadmin](https://www.pgadmin.org) or even better command-line tool [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html)?